# Node JS: how to view a downloaded image binary?

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, sails.js

I use Sails JS (applies to any **Node JS** framework) and a third party external **storage service** (I use SmartFile, but it may be S3 or anything).

For security reasons, the images are not public and I need an API key to access them.
Also, sharing the API key with the clients is not a good security practice.

What is the best practice to show the image to the client?

**Trivial solution:**

1. Download the binary from the server
2. Save it to a file on the server (what if the server is read-only?)
3. Add the file link to the view so the logged in user can see it

But this sounds to me as double effort, the server downloads it, then the client again.

Better ideas?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this side of things, but at least on S3/Cloudfront, I think you'd normally use your primary access key to generate a [temporary signed url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls-overview.html) that you can include in the link to the file that you render into your page. That way the file loads for anyone viewing your page, but the image is not public.

Answer (score 1):

Streams, baby.  [Streams!](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

Simplistic example using [request](https://github.com/request/request) (so `npm install request` first):

```
// api/controllers/ImageController.js

var request = require('request');

module.exports = {

  getImage: function(req, res) {

    // Determine which file to download, somehow
    var filePath = req.param('filePath');
    // Set the content header for the image
    res.header('content-type', 'image/jpeg');
    // Pipe the image from the external server to the client
    request.get("http://someExternalService.com" + filePath).pipe(res);

  }

};
```

So:

1. Get the API endpoint to retrieve the file
2. Set a header for the correct filetype
3. Stream the file from the API server → Sails → client

Not pictured here are the details like how to do authorization with the external storage service (probably an auth header) and determining the exact content type to set (probably by examining the file extension), but since the question was about how to get the image to the client without downloading it twice, this is all you need to know.